# Python Convert 1-D array to N-D array

Tags: python

I am new to python and want to change the data from 1-D array to N-D array.
Please see my sample data below:

```
a = array([['T-Shirts', '1 Piece'],
           ['Capris', 'Leggings', 'Skirts']], dtype=object)
```

and I want to get the data like:

```
array([[['T-Shirts'], ['1 Piece']],
       [['Capris'], ['Leggings'], ['Skirts']]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: missing some quotation marks?

Comment: Still missing quotation marks on the first block of code (`Skirts'`).  A suggestion is to organize your data and make sure it looks in good shape as a Python list before you load it into a Numpy array.

Comment: I added the quotation marks as suggested by original poster's comment on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43486172.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy does not support jagged arrays, which is what you are trying to get as your output.  Your best bet is to move your data to native Python lists.

```
a = [['T-Shirts,1 Piece'], ['Capris,Leggings,Skirts']]
out = [[[y] for y in x[0].split(',')] for x in a]
out

# returns:
[[['T-Shirts'], ['1 Piece']], [['Capris'], ['Leggings'], ['Skirts']]]
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply. for my output, I want ['T-Shirts', '1 Piece'] to be separated as ['T-Shirts'], ['1 Piece']

Answer (score 1):

It's easier using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
# note: removed useless sublists
x = ['T-Shirts,1 Piece', 'Capris,Leggings,Skirts']
pd.Series(x).str.split(',', expand=True)
```

That gives:

```
          0         1       2
0  T-Shirts   1 Piece    None
1    Capris  Leggings  Skirts
```

Answer (score 0):

### Set up

It looks like you're using the numpy package because your code has `array(...)` and `dtype=...` formatting. So, to prepare to show code examples, I did these commands:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([['T-Shirts', '1 Piece'], ['Capris', 'Leggings', 'Skirts']])
```

After those, when I enter:

```
a
```

I get this result (your starting point):

```
array([['T-Shirts', '1 Piece'], ['Capris', 'Leggings', 'Skirts']], dtype=object)
```

### Desired output

When I do this command:

```
[[[x] for x in l] for l in a]
```

I get this result:

```
[[['T-Shirts'], ['1 Piece']], [['Capris'], ['Leggings'], ['Skirts']]]
```

The command I ran was a Python list comprehension. It is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for making a list with for loops. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/756329) or by searching for "python list comprehension".

Note: I did not use numpy for that conversion. If you want the same kind of list you had before, you could place the code inside `np.array( )`, like this:

```
np.array([[[x] for x in l] for l in a])
```

The result of that command is:

```
array([[['T-Shirts'], ['1 Piece']], [['Capris'], ['Leggings'], ['Skirts']]], dtype=object)
```

### Bonus

Also, on a side note, you can do this:

```
[[x] for l in a for x in l]
```

and get this:

```
[['T-Shirts'], ['1 Piece'], ['Capris'], ['Leggings'], ['Skirts']]
```

Comment: @JohnZwinck he's using Numpy, I believe, hence the formatting of his array.

Comment: Hi Joseph, this is exactly what I want. Thanks so much! would you please explain more on [[x] for l in a for x in l]

Comment: @RyanMa I added some links you can use to find more information.